# How to append items to the masonry grid made with Colcade.js?

Tags: javascript, masonry

I have an array of Js objects which have quotes and its relevent data.

```
var quotes = [

    {
        'author': 'Rahul Morajker',
        'quote': `Upcoming Guest`,
        'image': 'img/guests/rahul.jpg',
        'ig': 'morajker',
        'marks': false
    },
    {
        'author': 'Akash Lamani',
        'quote': `Quote here`,
        'image': 'img/guests/akash.jpg',
        'ig': 'aakash_5520',
        'marks': true
    },
    {
        'author': 'Soham Naik',
        'quote': `Quote here`,
        'image': 'img/guests/soham.jpg',
        'ig': 'soham_scientist',
        'marks': true
    },

    {
        'author': 'Navish Naik',
        'quote': `Quote here`,
        'image': 'img/guests/navish.jpg',
        'ig': 'navish_naik',
        'marks': true
    },
    {
        'author': 'Aaron Vaz',
        'quote': `Quote here`,
        'image': 'img/guests/aaron.jpg',
        'marks': true
    }
]
```

Using a `forEach` loop I am populating the DOM with these quotes. These quotes are then placed in masonry fashion using [Colcade.js](https://github.com/desandro/colcade). But I don't want all the quotes to show at once, so only 4 of them show up and then another 4 are populated if the user clicks `Load more`. But I'm unaware of how to append these next four quotes into the existing masonry grid.
The documentation only mentions `colc.append(items)` and I can't figure out what `items` should be passed in `colc.append`. Whether it's a Javascript reference to each item or an array of the items or a nodelist.